# How can I pass the value and corresponding name of a checkbox when checked using javascript in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, checkbox

I'm very new to ajax/javascript so I will try my best to explain my problem. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function () {

        $("#chkFilter").on("click", "input", function (e) 
        {
            var filterCheckboxes = new Array();
            $("#chkFilter").find("input:checked").each(function () {
                //console.log($(this).val()); //works fine
                filterCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
                console.log($(this).val());

                //var filterCheckboxes = new Array();
                //for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                //    if (e[i].checked)
                //        filterCheckboxes.push(e[i].value);
                //}
            });
        console.log("calling ajax");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/tools/oppy/Default.aspx",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { UpdateQuery: filterCheckboxes }, // using the parameter name
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        });
        });
    });
```

Every time a checkbox is checked, ajax passes the data onto the server. Here is an example of some checkbox values after a few have been checked in the data form obtained from the Developer's Console:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
filterCheckboxes.push($(this).prop("name") + "=" + $(this).val());
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any recommendations on how to parse it on the server? I assume, given my code, will send it to the server as a URL string?

Comment: Well, i would use the substring method on the server to split the Request["UpdateQuery"] value.

Comment: Request["UpdateQuery"] - UpdateQuery is a method. From my understanding, UpdateQuery: filterCheckboxes means I'm passing the array to a method on the server. Would I still do Request[UpdateQuery] on page load?